# How to implement Peano numbers exponentiation in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I am trying to implement exponentiation with the code below, but a simple query like 2^1 (`ex(s(s(0)), s(0), Z).`) hangs forever.

```
nat(0).
nat(s(X)) :- nat(X).
su(0, X, X) :- nat(X).
su(s(X), Y, s(Z)) :- su(X, Y, Z).

mu(0, _, 0).
mu(s(X), Y, Z) :- su(Y, A, Z), mu(X, Y, A).

ex(_, 0, s(0)).
ex(X, s(Y), Z) :- mu(X, A, Z), ex(X, Y, A).
```

Comment: Did you use `trace.` to detect why it got stuck?

Comment: `trace` shows several calls making the Peano number infinitely bigger. So I inverted both the conditions in mu() and ex() and now it works at least for the case of completely defined queries.

Comment: The problem is that your code calls `mu/3` with the last two parameters as "free variables", and because of that `s/3` is called with three free variables, and will keep proposing solutions that are then eventually all reject by the recursive calls to `mu/3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, it is not efficient, because the `mu/3` is called with *two* free variables. Indeed:

```
ex(X, s(Y), Z) :- mu(X, A, Z), ex(X, Y, A).
```

Both `A` and `Z` are *unknown* at that moment (I have put them in boldface).

Now your `mu/2` is not capable of handling this properly. If we query `mu/3` with `mu(s(0), A, Z)`, we get:

```
?- mu(s(0), A, Z).
A = Z, Z = 0 ;
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

So it got stuck in infinite recursion as well.

This is due to the fact that it will tak the second clause of `mu/3`, and:

```
mu(s(X), Y, Z) :- su(Y, A, Z), mu(X, Y, A).
```

So `su/3` is called with three unknown variables. The effect of this is that `su/3` can keep proposing values "until the end of times":

```
?- su(A, B, C).
A = B, B = C, C = 0 ;
A = 0,
B = C, C = s(0) ;
A = 0,
B = C, C = s(s(0)) ;
A = 0,
...
```

even if the recursive `mu(X, Y, A)` rejects all these proposals, `su/3` will never stop proposing new solutions.

Therefore it might be better to keep that in mind when we design the predicates for `mu/3`, and `ex/3`.

We can for example use an *accumulator* here that accumulates the values, and returns the end product. The advantage of this, is that we work with real values when we make the `su/3` call, like:

```
mu(A, B, C) :-
    mu(A, B, 0, C).

mu(0, _, 0, S, S).
mu(s(X), Y, I, Z) :-
    su(Y, I, J),
    mu(X, Y, J, Z).
```

Now if we enter `mu/3` with only the first parameter fixed, we see:

```
?- mu(s(0), X, Y).
X = Y, Y = 0 ;
X = Y, Y = s(0) ;
X = Y, Y = s(s(0)) ;
X = Y, Y = s(s(s(0))) ;
...
?- mu(s(s(0)), X, Y).
X = Y, Y = 0 ;
X = s(0),
Y = s(s(0)) ;
X = s(s(0)),
Y = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
X = s(s(s(0))),
Y = s(s(s(s(s(s(0)))))) ;
...
...
```

So that means that we now at least do not get stuck in a loop for `mu/3` with only the first parameter fixed.

We can use the same strategy to define an `ex/3` predicate:

```
ex(X, Y, Z) :-
    ex(X, Y, s(0), Z).

ex(X, 0, Z, Z).
ex(X, s(Y), I, Z) :-
    mu(X, I, J),
    ex(X, Y, J, Z).
```

We then manage to calculate exponents like *2<sup>1</sup>* and *2<sup>2</sup>*:

```
?- ex(s(s(0)), s(0), Z).
Z = s(s(0)) ;
false.
?- ex(s(s(0)), s(s(0)), Z).
Z = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
false.
```

Note that the above has still some flaws, for example calculating for which powers the value is `4` will still loop:

```
?- ex(X, Y, s(s(s(s(0))))).
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

By rewriting the predicates, we can avoid that as well. But I leave that as an exercise.